# robots.txt file is probably invalid

Tags: indexing, web-crawler, robots.txt

this is my `robots.txt`. I want to only allow the base url `domain.com` for indexing and disallow all sub urls like `domain.com/foo` and `domain.com/bar.html`.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*/
```

Because I am not sure whether this is a valid syntax I tested it using Google Webmaster Tools. It shows me this message.

```
robots.txt file is probably invalid.
```

**Is my file valid? Is there a better way of only allowing the base url for indexing?**

Update: Google downloaded my `robots.txt` 4 hours ago. I think thats why it doesn't work. I will wait some time and if the problem stays I will update my question again.

Comment: I read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206602/robots-txt-how-to-allow-access-only-to-domain-root-and-no-deeper but did not understand the answer.

Comment: Here's another similar question that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43427/669611

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to a validator. It might help you work through any errors in the file.

[Robots.txt Checker](http://tool.motoricerca.info/robots-checker.phtml)

I checked on another validator, [robots.txt Checker](http://www.searchenginepromotionhelp.com/m/robots-text-tester/robots-checker.php), and this is what I got for the second line:

> Wildcard characters (like "*") are not allowed here The line below
>   must be an allow, disallow, comment or a blank line statement

This might be what you're looking for:

```
User-Agent: *
Allow: /index.html
Disallow: /
```

This assumes your homepage is index.html.

If index.php is your homepage, you should be able to swap out index.html for index.php.

```
User-Agent: *
Allow: /index.php
Disallow: /
```

On my dynamic websites that run through index.php, going to mydomain.com/index.php still takes me to the homepage, so the above should work.

Comment: index.html isn't my homepage because all requests lead to index.php wich manages the content and layout. So I need to allow the base domain only.

Comment: does going to yourdomain.com/index.php take you to the homepage?

Comment: yes because of redirection to yourdomain.com by .htaccess